# UILabel doesn't update after setting attributedText

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, swift3

I use MapKit to record running distance. I have the following code:

```
var runningDistance : Double = 0{
    didSet{
        guard let text = runningDistanceLabel.attributedText as? NSMutableAttributedString else{return}
        let range = NSMakeRange(0, 4)            
        let attributeString = NSAttributedString(string: String(format:"%.2f",runningDistance/1000.0), attributes: [
            NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "DINCondensed-Bold", size: 17)!       
            ])
        text.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: attributeString)
        runningDistanceLabel.attributedText = text

        print(runningDistanceLabel.text)
        print(runningDistanceLabel.attributedText)            
    }
}
```

When `userLocation` update, I calculate the distance and set `runningDistance`.

In console：

```
Optional("0.04公里")
Optional(0.04{
    NSFontAttributeName = "Optional(<UICTFont: 0x7ff79b7b7250> font-family: \"DIN Condensed\"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 17.00pt)";
}公里{
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7ff79d800110> font-family: \".PingFangSC-Regular\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14.00pt";
NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 2, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 4, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n    140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n    308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (\n), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation NO, HeaderLevel 0";
})
```

That shows the `runningDistanceLabel`'s `text` and `attributedText` has been set and changed. **But in simulator, the label's text remains unchanged.**

And if I replace:

```
runningDistanceLabel.attributedText = text
```

with:

```
runningDistanceLabel.text = "\(runningDistance)"
```

Then in simulator, the label's text can be changed normally.

What's wrong with my code about setting attributedText? How to set `attributedText` and update correctly in simulator?

Thank you very much!

**Edit:**

I am sure the `guard` has been passed because it has printed label's text and attributedText in console and I have added a breakpoint to test it.

I also try:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {[unowned self] in
    self.runningDistanceLabel.attributedText = text
}
```

But I still cannot update the label's text.

**Soluion**

And with **Rroobb**'s help, I add a line of code to set label's text before setting its attributedText:

```
runningDistanceLabel.text = String(format:"%.2f",runningDistance/1000.0) + "公里"
runningDistanceLabel.attributedText = text
```

And in simulator, the label's text can be updated now. Amazing!

In iOS document about `UILabel`'s `attributedText`:

> Assigning a new value to this property also replaces the value of the text property with the same string data, albeit without any formatting information.

It seems that setting `attributedText` can automatically change the `text` property.

But here I don't know why I should set `text` before setting `attributedText` in order to update the label's text.

Comment: Do you pass the `guard let text` lines? I'm wondering, since `runningDistanceLabel.attributedText` may be a `NSAttributedString` object and not a `NSMutableAttributedString` object, that you may go into the `return`.

Comment: Make sure the didSet is called on the main thread. ` runningDistanceLabel.attributedText = text runningDistanceLabel.setNeedsLayout()`

Comment: I have tried main thread and setNeedsLayout() , but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, I added two line of code :

```
 var runningDistance : Double = 0.0 {
    didSet{
        guard let text = runningDistanceLabel.attributedText as? NSMutableAttributedString else{

            return

        }

        let range = NSMakeRange(0, 4)
        runningDistanceLabel.text = String(format:"%.2f",runningDistance/1000.0) //here
        runningDistanceLabel.font = UIFont(name: "DINCondensed-Bold", size: 17) // here
        let attributeString = NSAttributedString(string: String(format:"%.2f",runningDistance/1000.0), attributes: [
            "NSFontAttributeName":UIFont(name: "DINCondensed-Bold", size: 17)!
            ])

        text.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: attributeString)
        runningDistanceLabel.attributedText = text


        print(runningDistanceLabel.text!)
        print(runningDistanceLabel.attributedText!)
    }
}
```

Comment: With your help, I just set `runningDistanceLabel`'s text before setting its `attributedText` and it works! Confusing, but amazing!

Comment: Just struggled with this for half an hour. The key really was to update the `text` property before `attributedText`, thanks a lot!

Comment: Skoua: Thank you.  setting text before attributedText did it for me. after hours of trying to find a solution